# Knockout - display placeholder when 'with' binding is undefined

Tags: knockout.js

Given an element that is bound via 'with' to an observable, how can I display a place holder element whilst the observable is 'undefined'?

The specific problem I'm trying to solve is an options binding which depends via the 'with' binding on the selected value of second, parent, options binding. Whilst the parent options binding is unselected, the child select list doesn't even exist in the DOM. This looks odd to the user as there is a gap until they make their first selection from the parent drop down and only then the child drop down appears.

Code looks something like this:

```
<select data-bind="options: parents,
                   optionsText: 'name',
                   value: selectedParent,
                   optionsCaption: 'Select parent'"></select>

<div data-bind="with: selectedParent">
    <select data-bind="options: children,
                   optionsText: 'name',
                   value: selectedChild,
                   optionsCaption: 'Select child'"></select>
</div>
```

Until the user makes a selection from the parent select, then there is a hole in my UI, where the child select will appear.

I understand why this is happening, because what should Knockout display in the child select, when its 'undefined'? However I'm looking for a workaround to make the UI look OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are worried about the drop down suddenly popping up on the screen and looking odd in the UI, why not show it initially but disable it until the `selectedParent` has a value.

I've moved the `with` binding out and updated the child `options` accordingly in addition to the new `enable` binding and default `disabled` element setting.

```js
class ViewModel {
  constructor() {
    this.parents = [{
      name: "A",
      children: [{ name: "A1" }, { name: "A2" }, { name: "A3" }]
    }, {
      name: "B",
      children: [{ name: "B1" }, { name: "B2" }, { name: "B3" }]
    }];
    this.selectedParent = ko.observable();
    this.selectedChild = ko.observable();
  }
}

const vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: parents,
                   optionsText: 'name',
                   value: selectedParent,
                   optionsCaption: 'Select parent'"></select>

<div>
  <select data-bind="options: selectedParent() ? selectedParent().children : [],
                   optionsText: 'name',  
                   value: selectedChild,
                   optionsCaption: 'Select child',
                   enable: selectedParent" disabled="disabled"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was playing about with some really ugly <!-- ko ifnot: selectedParent --> code, which would have achieved the same logic, but was ugly. You're solutions is very elegant!